# Allow any string for property definition Json Schema

Tags: jsonschema

I'm trying to use jsonschema to validate some simple json. I have the following:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "outputs": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "ANYSTRING": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "properties": {
                        "label": { "type": "string" },
                        "otherLabel": { "type": "string" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, I want any of the following to be valid:

```
{
    "outputs": {
        "this is a sample string": { "label": "test" },
        "another string": { },
        "and one last one": { "otherLabel": "dummy" } 
    }
}
```

(How) Can I have this wildcard string property denoted above as "ANYSTRING"?

Comment: Hi, what about changing the JSON to have the "ANYSTRING" inside a field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could use additionalProperties. Side note: a thing of type “string” can’t have properties, but “object” can.

```
"outputs": {
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "label": { "type": "string" }
    }
  }
}
```

- Shawn Silverman (JsonSchema Slack channel)